# Is it possible to create a dependency between two file names?

Tags: unit-testing, filenames, webstorm

If I create a file:

```
my_code.js
```

and then a file containing unit tests of this file:

```
test_my_code.js
```

is there a way to configure WebStorm (or any other trick?) that can ensure that if I rename `my_code.js` to `another_code.js` then `test_my_code.js` will automatically be renamed to `test_another_code.js`?

Comment: what system operate use?

Comment: I use MacOS Sierra (Version 10.12.1)

Comment: bash in linux, powershell windows is util?

Comment: Bash in linux is the util